# How is this type of illustration made?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

https://www.behance.net/gallery/8610251/PAUSE_Be-Responsible-Spread-the-word-Be-Conscious

> [image]

I really like these illustration but not sure if they are made on a tablet?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Those appear to be hand drawn sketches. This could be done in pencil, ink or using a tablet. Not all tablets and software can support this kind of drawing, though, so do your research before investing in one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say hand drawn artwork.

Anything drawn on paper can generally be made with a tablet. It's merely a matter of how comfortable an artist is with the tablet.

The bottom portions of the illustrations appear to have been done digitally, the runs and distortions. Most likely this was hand drawn then some application was used digitally to introduce the run, drips, and smears.

(*Not* everything done on a tablet can be drawn on paper).

Comment: The smearing/dripping effect seems to made digitally. Perhaps with Photoshop's *liquify* effect.

Comment: HA! I missed that aspect entirely, @Wolff `:)` I was looking at the tops, line work, etc. Didn't even catch the bottoms. Yup.. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's fully digital. Strokes `A` and `C` look like a brush was using a shape expression set to a pen pressure: it's quite common in chalk brushes. Stroke `B` looks like it's a one stroke with angle jitter set to tilt or direction (my examples on top are to illustrate stroke behaviour, not attempting to repeat the same texture).

Red color `C` looks very digital, the blood drop `D` isn't consistent with other strokes and very clean; the effect at  `E` was already mentioned and is 100% digital. Strokes at `F` have very clean edges for this roughness, etc, etc.

[image]

Check [Kyle's brushes](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/get-more-brushes-photoshop-cc-2018/) and especially Dry Media and Copier brushes for Photoshop at Adobe Website (they're free for CC subscribers), there're a lot of brushes to have similar effects. Two minutes with dry media brushes:

[image]